# Sequence Generator using Generator Name rather than Sequence name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sequence-generators

`

```
ENTITIES:
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_ITEM")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ORDER_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "ORDER_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "ORDER_GEN")
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Long orderId;
    @Column(name = "order_dt")
    private Date orderDt;
    @Column(length = 100, name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
...
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_ITEM")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ORDER_ITEM_ID_Gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ORDER_ITEM_ID_Gen", sequenceName = "ORDER_ITEM_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "order_Item_id")
    private Long orderItemId;
    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID")
    private Long orderId;
    @Column(length = 200, name = "content_id")
    private String contentId;
    @Column(length = 100, name = "business")
    private String business;
    @Column(length = 100, name = "media_type")
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMAN_ORDER_BY_BU")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderByBu {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ORDER_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "ORDER_ID", allocationSize = 1, name = "ORDER_SEQ")
    private Long orderBuId;
    @Column(name="orderId")
    private Long orderId;
    @Column(length=100, name="business")
    private String business;
    private Date createDt;
    @Column(length=100, name="status")
    private String status;
....
}`
```

Service Object

```
@Transactional
        public Order saveOrder(Order order) {
            log.info("saving order");
            try {
                Order savedOrder = OrderRepository.saveAndFlush(order);
                savedOrder.setOrderbyBus(saveOrderByBu(order));
                savedOrder.setOrderItems(saveOrderItem(order));
                log.info("order saved");
                return savedOrder;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error while saving order: {}", e.getMessage());
                throw new RuntimeException("Error while saving order", e);
            }
        }
```

Repositories

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order,Long> {...
}
public interface OrderItemsRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderItem,Long> {...
}
public interface setOrderbyBusRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderByBu,Long> {...
}
```

If I use the same sequence on all 3 entitiy it works fine

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ORDER_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "ORDER_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "ORDER_GEN")
```

When I change it to use a different sequence I get this error

```
2023-07-28 15:31:10 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select order_item_id_gen.nextval from dual
2023-07-28 15:31:10 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

So I tried using the Sequence name as the generator name

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ORDER_ITEM_ID_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ORDER_ITEM_ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "ORDER_ITEM_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "order_Item_id")
    private Long orderItemId;
```

Now I get this error when booting up Spring boot

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the [EMAN_ORDER_ITEM_ID_SEQ] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1].
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.configure(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

allocationSize = 1)

I expect to be able to use 3 different sequences
I can use any Sequence I want as long as they are all the same
I am using Springboot 3.0.8
JAVA 17

Answer (score 0):

Few wrong things there:

- **Sequence Does Not Exist** – meaning that the `ORDER_ITEM_ID_SEQ` you're trying to use does not exist, please ensure it's really created at this step
- **Mismatch between allocation size and increment size** – it seems that the increment size set in your `@SequenceGenerator` (allocationSize) and the actual increment size in the database are different, please ensure they match. If the increment is 1 in the database, the `allocationSize` should be 1 in your annotation too

Comment: The Sequence does exist in the Oracle database the error occurs if I try to use different sequences on the entities

Comment: This error Mismatch between allocation size and increment size occurs if I name the generator name and the sequence name the same name. I tried this because it was using the generator name as the sequence name

Comment: The Sequence are in the database and the allocations sizes are set to 1